# i am trying to convert my kivy and kivymd python file into apk . My file contains video also

Tags: kivy, kivymd, buildozer

[this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xmdiC.jpg)

I tried various methods advised by youtubers but none of them worked. I only want to successfully convert my python file into apk. A big error message is shown, I am not able to solve it. How can I solve it with simple steps

Answer (score 1):

You can use Buildozer to create an APK.

First things first, make sure you have Buildozer installed (use **pip install buildozer**).

Then, use the **buildozer init** command to create a build.spec file.

Open the build.spec file and edit it according to your app's needs. Make sure to configure the sections correctly, including the [app] section where you define your app's details.

Navigate to the root folder of your project where the build.spec file is located.

Run the **buildozer android release deploy** command. This will create an APK that can be found in the BIN folder of your project.